Latent variable demonstration with only 3 variables
I collected data for anxiety (ANX), depression (DEP), and posttraumatic stress syndrome (PTSD) symptoms. Spearman's correlation results are the following (***p < .001):

ANX and DEP: r = 0.5452 ***
ANX and PTSD: r = 0.5568 ***
DEP and PTSD: r = 0.4599 ***

I thought about using the confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) to see whether I could confirm the existence of a single latent variable.
If I'm not mistaken, the minimum number of variables to carry out a CFA is 3. However, the issue will be that the model will fit perfectly with zero degree of freedom putting into question the model.
Power analyses show that the sample sizes I should've had were the following:

ANX: n = 99
DEP: n = 99
PTSD: n = 53

Although I collected n > 400, all the variables violate the assumption of normality and have some outliers.
My question: Are there any statistical models that can show the existence of a latent variable knowing that there are only 3 variables, and that the data violates the assumption of normality and have outliers?

Why confirmatory FA? Apart from the issues with number off variables and normality, this seems like a case for exploratory FA.  You don't have a factor structure to confirm (at least, you haven't mentioned one).

Thanks for your comment @Peter Flom. The reason is because the latent variable has already been confirmed in many studies. But in any case, even if I do an EFA, if I'm not mistaken, the problem will be the same… what do you think?
